# Google Reader Play Alternatives with Slideshow

Tags: rss, slideshow

Are there any other RSS Readers featuring a Slideshow through the articles than Google Reader Play?

Can be Desktop App, Browser Plugin, iOS App, etc. I'd rather prefer a non-webapp as I'd like to provide an RSS source within my local network.

Comment: It also can be a blog viewer program.

Comment: Why do you insist on a slideshow? Most RSS readers include some form of alert - isn't this enough?

Comment: Ok, more background info: I want to have the slideshow of the feed (and maybe some comments) playing on a screen people in my company walk by daily. So they get informed about a range of the latest news. Publishing new information would be as simple as writing a new blog post to this internal blog.

Comment: may I know why not google reader play?

Comment: Because we have an internal RSS source which is not allowed to leak to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The article [RSS-powered Windows 7 desktop slideshows](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090126/rss-powered-windows-7-desktop-slideshows/) describes how
in Windows 7 it is possible to create RSS powered slideshows for your desktop using [Windows 7 Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190.aspx#theme_pack).

This utilizes the [Windows RSS Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686418.aspx) which automatically refreshes and download feed enclosures in the background.

If a desktop theme can serve as slideshow, then this is one way to achieve your goal.

The links in my post contain many pointers to more information and examples (and the comments are also useful).

[EDIT]

If a desktop theme is not the solution,
I think that you will need to develop your slideshow.
The best tool available seems to be [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) as demonstrated in [AJAX Slide Show](http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/slideshow/index.html).

Here are some resources that might help :

[Using Google AJAX Feed API to create your own Slide Show](http://www.liens-du-vin.ch/slide-show-media-rss.html)
[Build an RSS Slideshow](http://rssslideshow.algaze.org/)

Comment: Thank you, I knew already of this possibility. As far as I have understood, this only displays enclosed images, but I want the full blog entry with text too. I'll wait for some other answers before I award the bounty.

Comment: I have added some more info. Please do not award the bounty if my answer hasn't pointed you to a solution.

Comment: As I understand it, with Google Feed API, the feed is downloaded and processed by Google's servers. This will not be possible with an intranet-only feed like in my scenario.

Comment: (1) Google Feed API is nothing but a javascript library, so in theory can be used offline, but in practice I have never tried it. (2) I have come across the Chrome app [PurpleGene Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgjiekambmjckfnbedchbjiamngedppn?hl=en-US) which might interest you. (3) The series of 5 articles "PhoneGap RSS Reader" could be useful (first article is [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/11/PhoneGap-RSS-Reader)).

Comment: Thanks for the additional infos, I'll have a look into them. Ad 1: As far as I have understood, the lib sends the feed to the Google servers for processing.